# NodeJS and front-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, pug

I'm working on a project - where i would like to split the logic into micro-services like:

1. DB layer / service which run 24X7 and store some live data i db
2. API layer / service - exposing the data, making calculation evt.
3. Fron-end - draw some graphs (by using the API) in the browser

Bullet no. 1 and 2 are made i NodeJS. I'm currently playing with Dygraphs which is pure java script and therefore i also use jQuery...

Im comming from a .NET world... and thereby - new to NodeJS ect...
How would you recommend me to "connect" NodeJS and the front-end?

Right now - i made a test with pure html, js/jQuery... but of course i need to be able to use NodeJS to call the API ect...and render the graphs based on the returned data... so how do i accomplish this the best/easiest way?

Via Jade, Angular or some thing else?

Also - what REST api would you recommend?

Comment: This question does not follow the guidelines for stack overflow.  It asks an extremely general architectural question and asks for third party tool recommendations and asks non-specific architecture quesstions which makes it both too broad and off-topic for here.  Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I asked the best i could... if its not good enough - ask me some details...so i can help you - help me...why not use our energy on some thing concrete and helping each other - instead of this?

Comment: Please read: [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It is your responsibility to frame a question that fits the guidelines here. In particular, you should not be asking for third party software recommendations as that is off-topic here and you must ask a SPECIFIC question that can be answered in a few paragraphs, not something that might take several chapters in a book to teach (which is what you have now). This isn't the right place for this type of question.

Comment: I understand - thus my question can be answered in a few paragraphs... IF you have enough experience i guess... like: Jade is the most used framework together with NodeJS and fits most cases... Otherwise tell me and other new people where to go for finding the right info ;-)

Comment: You will really need to understand better how to use this site.  A recommendation of Jade is just one person's opinion based on their experiences and needs.  There are literally hundreds of template engines that all have unique benefits.  There is NO "best" template engine for node.js.  It depends entirely upon your needs, how you like your templates to work, what style syntax you like, what specific features you find important or required, what tools you like, etc...  In other words, it's almost entirely opinion and questions who's answers are mostly opinion are NOT allowed here by policy.

Comment: In other words, this is the wrong site for the high-level kinds of architectural and library selection questions you're asking.  You will have to do research on those topics elsewhere on the internet.  If you do that research and then have very specific questions like: "Can a Jade template be used to create this specific type of page" (where you show exactly what you're trying to create), then you can come back here to ask that specific type of question.  Or maybe you ask: "How do I generate this portion of my page using Jade?" where you show the desired end-result HTML and what you tried.

Comment: I get it - Thank you friend :-)

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of tutorial on the web that could help you to do such a thing, I can send you some if you want?

Personally I'm using nodejs and angularjs, but it really depend on your project.
If you want to build an SPA (Single Page Application), I think angularjs will match. If you don't, don't use it! angular is a really good framework but you have to learn it.

Also I use node on an nginx server which one is listening on port 80. When client asks for an html page, nginx *catch* the request and routing it to a particular directory on my server.
When client is asking for an url such as **myDomain/api/***something* it sending it to the node server (on port 3000).

Hope it helps

Comment: Tutorials are great - WHEN you know WHAT to look for - but i dont... of course i could search and read for days... but why - some people out there know the exact answer to this... There are so many options, combinations, cons and pros... I need an answer from some one with a lot of experience...